# How to run Karate and Gatling with Gradle build system

Tags: karate

I'm trying to run a Karate test as a Gatling performance test.  My entire setup works perfect when using Maven.  I am being forced to use Gradle however.  When trying to run under Gradle the below disaster unfolds.

Appreciate any ideas what might be causing KarateAction to crash.

**MyAPI.scala**

```
class MyAPI extends Simulation {
    val protocol = karateProtocol(
        "/myendpoint" -> Nil
    )

    val action = karateFeature("classpath:org/mycompany/karate/tests/myAPI.feature@test=myTag")

    setUp(
        scenario("my-api")
            .exec(action)
            .inject(rampUsersPerSec(1) to (5) during (5 seconds))
            .protocols(protocol)
    )
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        karateVersion = '0.9.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'scala'

configurations {
    gatling
}

dependencies {
    testCompile("com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:${karateVersion}")
    testCompile("com.intuit.karate:karate-mock-servlet:${karateVersion}")
    testCompile("com.intuit.karate:karate-junit4:${karateVersion}")
    testCompile("com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:${karateVersion}")
    testCompile("net.masterthought:cucumber-reporting:3.8.0")

    gatling "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.8"
    gatling "io.gatling:gatling-app:3.0.2"
    gatling "io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.0.2"
    gatling "com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:${karateVersion}"
}

sourceSets {
    simulations {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java/org/mycompany/karate/perf']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java/org/mycompany/karate/perf']
        }

        compileClasspath += configurations.gatling
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/java')
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
}

test {
    systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

task gatlingRun(type: JavaExec) {
    description = 'Run Gatling Tests'
    new File("${buildDir}/reports/gatling").mkdirs()

    classpath = sourceSets.simulations.runtimeClasspath += configurations.gatling

    main = "io.gatling.app.Gatling"
    args = [
        '-s', 'org.mycompany.karate.perf.MyAPI',
        '-sf', 'src/test/java/org/mycompany/karate/perf',
        '-rf', "${buildDir}/reports/gatling"
    ]
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```

**command line**

```
gradle gatlingRun
```

**command line output**

```
> Task :compileSimulationsJava NO-SOURCE

> Task :compileSimulationsScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.
there were 6 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
one warning found

> Task :processSimulationsResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :simulationsClasses

> Task :gatlingRun
16:40:27.238 [main] INFO io.gatling.core.config.GatlingConfiguration$ - Gatling will try to use 'gatling.conf' as custom config file.
16:40:27.598 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
16:40:28.242 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO io.gatling.core.stats.writer.ConsoleDataWriter - Initializing
16:40:28.242 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO io.gatling.core.stats.writer.LogFileDataWriter - Initializing
16:40:28.248 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO io.gatling.core.stats.writer.ConsoleDataWriter - Initialized
16:40:28.253 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO io.gatling.core.stats.writer.LogFileDataWriter - Initialized
Simulation org.mycompany.karate.perf.MyAPI started...
16:40:28.359 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction - 'classpath:org/mycompany/karate/tests/myAPI.feature@test=myTag' crashed on session Session(my-api,1,1558395628341,Map(),0,OK,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$329/1759250827@7cee98de), forwarding to the next one
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.intuit.karate.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:55)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser.parse(FeatureParser.java:75)
        at com.intuit.karate.FileUtils.parseFeatureAndCallTag(FileUtils.java:155)
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner.callAsync(Runner.java:183)
        at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.execute(KarateAction.scala:77)
        at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang(Action.scala:38)
        at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang$(Action.scala:38)
        at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.io$gatling$core$action$ChainableAction$$super$$bang(KarateAction.scala:37)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ChainableAction.$bang(Action.scala:63)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ChainableAction.$bang$(Action.scala:61)
        at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.io$gatling$core$action$ExitableAction$$super$$bang(KarateAction.scala:37)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ExitableAction.$bang(BlockExit.scala:138)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ExitableAction.$bang$(BlockExit.scala:136)
        at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.$bang(KarateAction.scala:37)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Workload.startUser(Workload.scala:55)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Workload.injectUser(Workload.scala:64)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload.$anonfun$injectBatch$1(OpenWorkload.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload.$anonfun$injectBatch$1$adapted(OpenWorkload.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.UserStream.withStream(UserStream.scala:58)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload.injectBatch(OpenWorkload.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.$anonfun$inject$1(Injector.scala:60)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.$anonfun$inject$1$adapted(Injector.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:213)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.io$gatling$core$controller$inject$Injector$$inject(Injector.scala:59)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Injector.scala:92)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Injector.scala:82)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent(FSM.scala:684)
        at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent$(FSM.scala:681)
        at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.InjectorFSM.processEvent(InjectorFSM.scala:37)
        at akka.actor.FSM.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:678)
        at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:672)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
        at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:24)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
16:40:28.359 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG io.gatling.core.action.Exit - End user #1
16:40:28.360 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload - Start user #1
16:40:28.363 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload - Injecting 4 users in scenario my-api, continue=true
16:40:28.364 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector - End user #1
16:40:29.347 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload - Injecting 0 users in scenario my-api, continue=true
16:40:29.373 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction - 'classpath:org/mycompany/karate/tests/myAPI.feature@test=myTag' crashed on session Session(my-api,2,1558395629372,Map(),0,OK,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$329/1759250827@7cee98de), forwarding to the next one
```

Comment: Kirt do you have sample repo for the above project, Curretnly, I am trying to have a test against the actual server and then also have the performance test for the same, While trying to execute I am facing the issue of User-defined Simulation class features.EmployeeSimulation could not be loaded reference repo "https://github.com/reachbharathan/Karate-Sample-Test-Framework".

Comment: @BharathanKumaran i don't have a sample repo.  if you're having the same issue the accepted answer solved my problems.  i would suggest searching the following link for the word "gradle" https://github.com/intuit/karate too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess.

Your `build.gradle` defines `src/test/java` as resource folder:

```
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/java')
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
```

The [karate gatling demo](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-gatling/pom.xml#L40) defines `src/test/scala` as resource folder.

This is necessary, because otherwise the `*.feature` files next to your scala/java source files are not treated as part of the resulting artifact.

Furthermore, you are using the classpath of the `simulation` source set when running gatling test. Make sure, that your `*.feature` are included in that classpath.

As an alternative, you can put your `*.feature` files under `src/test/resources/com/your/package`, but this increases "the distance" between your feature and source code files.

**Debugging Hint:**
Print the file tree of your `build/resources` folder in order to check whether or not the feature files are included in the resulting build artifact and that the path matches the path you are referencing in your runner.

Let me know if this was useful!

Comment: I'm not sure if src/test/scala needs to be defined as a resource folder?  I say that because https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo doesn't specify one and it runs successfully.  I also noticed that my *.feature files are in /resources and my *.class files are in /classes and i can run 'gradle test' with success.  Not sure if you were implying *.feature should live side-by-side with *.class files?

Comment: Regarding my last comment I think you clarified this below that they would need to live side-by-side only when using relative paths.

Answer (score 4):

I have a gradle project with scala and java, and had to create a gradle task to move resources to the right folder, in order to make them available.

```
task copyResources(type: Copy) {
  from ("src/test/java/") {
    include "/**/*.feature"
    include "karate-config*.js"
    include "logback*.xml"
    include "/**/*.csv"
    include "/**/*.json"
  }
  into "$buildDir/classes/java/test/"

}
```

Comment: Having `*.feature` files next to the `*.class` files is necessary when using the relative path feature like `Runner.runFeature(getClass(), "any-karate.feature", args, false)`.

Should be fixed with https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/737.

Feature file location lookup via `classpath:` works when declaring source code folder as resource folder.